# Как воспроизвести <audio> с задержкой?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть некий звук, который нужно воспроизвести через 3 секунды после загрузки станицы

---

А если 2 аудио на странице, первое должно сразу воспроизводиться (воспроизводится), а второе через 3 секунды? Как обратиться ко второму аудио?

Comment: Как вариант - добавить в начало аудиотрека 3 секунды тишины.

Comment: так уж вышло, что без клика - нельзя включить аудио

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, вроде всё можно. Есть костыли с autoplay muted и с audio.play().catch(e => audio.play()).

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, в конце сентября работало :)

Comment: @Qwertiy не работает - https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/WNNvZmo?editors=1010 `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.` вот если заставить кликнуть - то работает

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, с autoplay работает https://jsfiddle.net/qjbm9ezf/, а вот с catch перестало https://jsfiddle.net/mtukzfec/.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100783/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-stranger-in-the-q).

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/qjbm9ezf/

На jsfiddle работает, в сниппете что-то не хочет...

```js
setTimeout(function () {
  var audio = document.querySelector('audio')
  
  audio.muted = false
  audio.currentTime = 0
  audio.play()
}, 3000)
```

```html
<audio autoplay muted>
  <source src="https://www.scottsmitelli.com/static-articles/2008/hypno-angrymachine.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  <source src="https://www.scottsmitelli.com/static-articles/2008/hypno-angrymachine.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = () => {
    setTimeout(() => document.querySelector('audio').play(), 3000)
};
```

Comment: В целом - нет, это не сработает, читайте комменты под вопросом

Answer (score 0):

**NOV 2019**

Из соображений безопасности - без клика невозможно включить звук на странице, а если клик (не важно куда) уже был совершен - помогут решения из соседних ответов.

работает `autoplay` для тега `video`, но если у него стоит `mute`, вероятно, из тех же соображений...

PS: Я все проверяю в Google Chrome, вероятно в каких-то браузерах и сработает.